# table of contents no word separation

Tags: table-of-contents

Is it possible to have in the toc no word separation but have a word separation in the chaptername:

For example:

```
Contents

1. max Mustermann


Chapter 
Max Muster-
mann
```

Comment: Yes, use `\chapter[ToC entry]{body entry}`...

Comment: ok, got this. But is there no way to define it in the preamble?

Comment: This depends on how your `\chapter`s are formatted, I guess. For example, are you manually breaking the line in the chapter body title?

Comment: No I do not breaking the line manually. Try to do it with a package \usepackage[breaklinks = true]{hyperref}. But this wont work

Comment: Please provide a minimal example that replicates your issue. Without that it's difficult to guess what the problem might be.

Comment: @mvp285286: Please do not ask [the same question with MWE again](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/348308/prevent-word-separation-in-table-of-contents) if you are ask for a MWE, but add a MWE to your already existing question.

Answer (score 3):

You can supply an alternative ToC-specific entry for any `\chapter` using the optional argument:

```
\chapter[<ToC entry>]{<body entry>}
```

This is typically convenient if you have non-standard formatting options you wish maintain in the body that may not be valuable in the ToC.

Answer (score 0):

Write into the preamble (assuming that you are in onecolumn mode}

```
\makeatletter
\def\@chapter[#1]#2{%
   \if@mainmatter
     \refstepcounter{chapter}%
     \typeout{\@chapapp\space\thechapter.}%
     \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\protect\numberline{\thechapter}\mbox{#1}}%
   \else
     \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\mbox{#1}}%
   \fi
   \chaptermark{#1}%
   \addtocontents{lof}{\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}%
   \addtocontents{lot}{\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}%
   \@makechapterhead{#2}%
   \@afterheading
  }
  \makeatother
```

Comment: Be carefull: Depending on the class and packages that have been used this could break things. So you should at least use a `\CheckCommand` to make sure, that the original definition of `\@chapter` is the expected (and to change) one. Alternatively you could use [`xpatch`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/xpatch) to do only the needed changes if the definition contains the expected code sequence.