# prevent word separation in table of contents

Tags: table-of-contents

How can I remove the word separation in table of contents, please have a look at the image. I knwo I can do it with `\chapter[<ToC entry>]{<body entry>}`, but I need a solution in the preambel.

```
\documentclass[10pt,final]{scrbook}
\usepackage{titletoc} % modify toc title
\usepackage{lipsum} % dummy text
\usepackage{anyfontsize} % change fontsize  
\usepackage{tocloft} % design toc
\usepackage{framed, xcolor}
\usepackage[english,ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{helvet}
\usepackage{endnotes}
\usepackage{titlesec}

%%% Change the title of toc
%%% Change "Contents" size \small, \huge, \Large,... 
\addto\captionsngerman{\renewcommand{\contentsname}{\normalfont\slshape\large{Contents}}}

% section itshape
\titleformat*{\section}{\itshape}
\titleformat*{\subsection}{\itshape}
%\titleformat*{\tableofcontents}{\itshape}

% Spacing between section and text
% Syntax: \titlespacing*{<command>}{<left>}{<before-sep>}{<after-sep>}
\titlespacing*{\subsection}{0cm}{0.84cm}{0.42cm}

\titlespacing*{\section}{0cm}{0.84cm}{0.42cm}

% Spacing between chapter and author 
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0cm}{0.84cm}{0.84cm}

% Spacing between chapterAndAuthor and section (?)
%\titlespacing*{\chapterAndAuthor}{0cm}{1.5cm}{1cm}

%%% Chapter style
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\normalfont}{\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}{12pt}{\Large}

% Display chapters in the Table of Contents
\titlecontents{chapter}
  [0pt]% Left margin, optional
  {}% Code insertet above
  {\mdseries}% Numbered-entryformat
  {\mdseries}% Numberless-format
  {\contentspage\vskip1.5ex} % add dotfill and pagenumber, and some vertical space between entries

% Custom command to keep the author on the same page of chaptertitle, and above it.
\newcommand{\chapterAndAuthor}[2]{%
  % #1: Author
  % #2: Chaptertitle
  \clearpage
  % Keep the author and chaptertitle on same page
  \begingroup\let\cleardoublepage\relax\let\clearpage\relax
  % Set the author style
  {\fontsize{12}{14}\itshape \noindent #1}\par
  % Bring the chaptertitle closer to the authortitle
  \vspace{-0.21cm}
  % Add an entry to the Table of Contents, with the name of 
  % the author in emph and the chapter title
  \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{%
    \texorpdfstring{%
      \protect\parbox[b]{\dimexpr\textwidth-15.5pt}{
        {\normalfont\itshape {#1}}%
        \endgraf\vspace{0cm}
        \leftskip=1em #2 \dotfill
      }%
    }{#2}%
  }
  % Print the chapter
  \chapter*{#2}
  \endgroup
}

\pagestyle{plain}

\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphics}
\usepackage{supertabular}

%SEITENLAYOUT%
 \usepackage[paperheight=21.0cm,paperwidth=13.5cm,twoside,textwidth=10.3cm,textheight=16.3cm,nohead,pdftex]{geometry}

%SCHRIFTGRÃSSEN%
\usepackage{fix-cm}

\makeatletter
\g@addto@macro\normalsize{\fontsize{10.0pt}{12.0pt}\selectfont} %\fontsize{Fontgröße}{Grundlinienabstand}
\g@addto@macro\footnotesize{\fontsize{9.0pt}{11.0pt}\selectfont} %\fontsize{Fontgröße}{Grundlinienabstand}
\makeatother


\usepackage[hyphens]{url}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage[colorlinks=false, pdfborder={0 0 0}, breaklinks = true]{hyperref}
\urlstyle{same}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% end preambel %%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\clearpage


\chapterAndAuthor{The name of the first author, The name of second author and The name of the third author}{Test Chapter One Test Chapter One Test Chapter One Test Chapter One Test Chapter One Test Chapter One Test Chapter One}

\noindent\lipsum[1]

\chapterAndAuthor{Johanna von Orleans, Charles de Secondat, Baron de MontesquieuMontesquieu, , Albert Einstein}{Test Chapter Two Test Chapter Two Test Chapter Two Test Chapter Two Test Chapter Two Test Chapter Two Test Chapter Two}

\noindent\lipsum[1]

\chapterAndAuthor{The name of the first author, The name of second author and The name of the third author}{Test Chapter Three Test Chapter Three Test Chapter Three Test Chapter Three Test Chapter Three Test Chapter Three Test Chapter Three}

\noindent\lipsum[1]



\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: is this not exactly the same question as your previous one?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: In practice you're absolutely right. But in theory the previous question could be a question about how to prevent line breaks in the table of contents. Here the example show, that only hyphenation should be prevented. And the answers to the previous questions also show how to prevent line breaks, while the answers here mostly show how to prevent hyphenation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Package [`hyphenat`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/hyphenat) provides command `\nohyphens` to prevent text from hyphenation:

```
\usepackage{hyphenat}
\newcommand{\chapterAndAuthor}[2]{%
  % #1: Author
  % #2: Chaptertitle
  \clearpage
  % Keep the author and chaptertitle on same page
  \begingroup\let\cleardoublepage\relax\let\clearpage\relax
  % Set the author style
  {\fontsize{12}{14}\itshape \noindent #1}\par
  % Bring the chaptertitle closer to the authortitle
  \vspace{-0.21cm}
  % Add an entry to the Table of Contents, with the name of 
  % the author in emph and the chapter title
  \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{%
    \texorpdfstring{%
      \protect\parbox[b]{\dimexpr\textwidth-15.5pt}{
        {\protect\normalfont\protect\itshape\protect\nohyphens{#1}}%
        \protect\endgraf\protect\vspace{0cm}
        \leftskip=1em #2\protect\dotfill
      }%
    }{#2}%
  }
  % Print the chapter
  \chapter*{#2}
  \endgroup
}
```

Nevertheless, this would result in very ugly spacing of the example text:

[image: ugly result]

because justification is still active. Better could be to use `\raggedright` for the authors:

```
\newcommand{\chapterAndAuthor}[2]{%
  % #1: Author
  % #2: Chaptertitle
  \clearpage
  % Keep the author and chaptertitle on same page
  \begingroup\let\cleardoublepage\relax\let\clearpage\relax
  % Set the author style
  {\fontsize{12}{14}\itshape \noindent #1}\par
  % Bring the chaptertitle closer to the authortitle
  \vspace{-0.21cm}
  % Add an entry to the Table of Contents, with the name of 
  % the author in emph and the chapter title
  \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{%
    \texorpdfstring{%
      \protect\parbox[b]{\dimexpr\textwidth-15.5pt}{
        {\protect\raggedright\protect\normalfont\protect\itshape#1%
        \protect\endgraf}\protect\vspace{0cm}
        \leftskip=1em #2\protect\dotfill
      }%
    }{#2}%
  }
  % Print the chapter
  \chapter*{#2}
  \endgroup
}
```

[image: raggedright used]

BTW: Have a look at the warnings in your `log` file, e.g.:

```
Class scrbook Warning: Usage of package `titlesec' together
(scrbook)              with a KOMA-Script class is not recommended.
(scrbook)              I'd suggest to use the package only
(scrbook)              if you really need it, because it breaks several
(scrbook)              KOMA-Script features, i.e., option `headings' and
(scrbook)              the extended optional argument of the section
(scrbook)              commands.
(scrbook)              Nevertheless, using requested
(scrbook)              package `titlesec' on input line 14.
```

and serveral

```
Package titlesec Warning: Non standard sectioning command detected
(titlesec)                Using default spacing and no format.
```

and

```
Package scrbook Warning: Activating an ugly workaround for a missing
(scrbook)                feature of package `titlesec` on input line 14.
```

I think, you are using a not recommended combination of classes and packages.
Maybe it would be better to use `\chapterlinesformat` or `\setchapterprefix` and `\addchaptertocentry` to add the author information to the heading and the table of contents entry.

Answer (score 0):

It is the typical use of a `\mbox` which is implemented like this :
     `\mbox{your chain of characters}`

This prevents your chain from hyphenation. Use it with extreme caution since it gets ugly very soon.

EDIT :

If you want it to prevent hyphenation in the ToC alone you can do this :

```
 \chapter[\mbox{your chain of characters}]{your chain of characters}
```

Doing so the mboxed title will be put in the ToC and the other one will be used as title.

EDIT 2 : Replace your command definition by this one :

```
\newcommand{\chapterAndAuthor}[2]{%
 % #1: Author
 % #2: Chaptertitle
\clearpage
 % Keep the author and chaptertitle on same page
\begingroup\let\cleardoublepage\relax\let\clearpage\relax
 % Set the author style
{\fontsize{12}{14}\itshape \noindent #1}\par
 % Bring the chaptertitle closer to the authortitle
\vspace{-0.21cm}
 % Add an entry to the Table of Contents, with the name of 
 % the author in emph and the chapter title
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{%
\texorpdfstring{%
  \protect\parbox[b]{\dimexpr\textwidth-15.5pt}{
    {\normalfont\itshape {\mbox{#1}}}%
    \endgraf\vspace{0cm}
    \leftskip=1em #2 \dotfill
   }%
}{#2}%
}
 % Print the chapter
\chapter*{#2}
\endgroup
}
```

Which is an adaptation of the previous solution to your previous command.

Comment: If done this way there will be no hyphenation in the text Body too, not just the ToC!

Comment: @Guilherme Zanotelli Normally the edited version should work.

Comment: That works, yes. But not for the OP as he/she uses a custom `\chapter` called `\chapterAndAuthor` whithout possibility for the optional argument. `:/`

Comment: Now that should work with the second edit

Answer (score 0):

You could switch the hyphenation patterns to the `nil` language inside the table of contents. The problem is that any language switch it the document also adds `\select@language{newlang}` to the `.toc` file, so just putting

```
\hyphenrules{nil}
```

before `\tableofcontents` doesn't help. So, first, add the `nil` language to the babel languages list:

```
\usepackage[nil,english,ngerman]{babel}
```

second, define your own table of contents macro which will disable hyphenation introduced by `\select@language`:

```
\makeatletter
\def\mytableofcontents{%
\let\select@language@orig\select@language
\def\select@language##1{\select@language@orig{##1}\hyphenrules{nil}}%
\tableofcontents
\let\select@language\select@language@orig
}
\makeatother
```

third, use this `\mytableofcontents` instead of `\tableofcontents`

Answer (score 0):

To disable hyphenation temporarily you can use `\foreignlanguage{nohyphenation}{<text>}`. You probably want to have no hyphenation in the ToC but keep it in the document body, so you have to disable it only inside the ToC. since you're using custom commands you must change them accordinly.

This is the command you need to change:

```
\newcommand{\chapterAndAuthor}[2]{%
  % #1: Author
  % #2: Chaptertitle
  \clearpage
  % Keep the author and chaptertitle on same page
  \begingroup\let\cleardoublepage\relax\let\clearpage\relax
  % Set the author style
  {\fontsize{12}{14}\itshape \noindent #1}\par
  % Bring the chaptertitle closer to the authortitle
  \vspace{-0.21cm}
  % Add an entry to the Table of Contents, with the name of 
  % the author in emph and the chapter title
  \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{%
    \texorpdfstring{%
      \protect\parbox[b]{\dimexpr\textwidth-15.5pt}{
        {\normalfont\itshape{\foreignlanguage{nohyphenation}{#1}}}% << HERE WE CHANGED
        \endgraf\vspace{0cm}
        \leftskip=1em #2 \dotfill
      }%
    }{#2}%
  }
  % Print the chapter
  \chapter*{#2}
  \endgroup
}
```

Then we get no hyphenation inside the ToC:

[image]

But they still work inside the document:

[image]